# Inline list with hanging indent

Tags: html, css, list, inline

In HTML, I'm laying out an unordered list something like this:

```
Fruit: Apple, Banana, Cherry, Durian...
```

I am treating the word "Fruit: " as generated content. I want for the list to be able to wrap so that the second line is flush left with the first "Apple."

My current attempt at this is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2t8cq/2/). I've included a background color just to highlight the weird close-but-no-cigar spacing.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the exact correct method, but simply changing the -4em to -2.2em seems to get the trick done. Not sure how it tests across browsers or with font size changes, but it works as a start:

```
li:first-child:before {
    content: 'fruits: ';
    margin-left: -2.2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2t8cq/4/

*Update: This method does break down as font size increases or decreases.*

Answer (score 0):

What you need is typically done using a DEFINITION LIST. You will need to style it accordingly.

```
<dl>
     <dt>Fruit:</dt>
     <dd>Apple</dd>
     <dd>Banana</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: This would create new lines for each of the entries. I think OP is looking for all of the results to appear on a single wrapping line in paragraph style.

Comment: Using a DL isn't necessarily a bad idea, but it doesn't get me any closer to being able to style it the way I want.

Comment: @AdamRice: If you put all of your results into a single definition it might be usable. You might have to mess with the positioning a little bit to get the `dt` and the `dd` to start on the same line, but you should get a consistent indentation.

Answer (score 0):

OK, [here's what I came up with](http://jsfiddle.net/2t8cq/5/). It uses positioning instead of margins, which seems a little ugly, but it does work. I'm still open to other solutions.

The relevant part:

```
    ul {
        margin: 0 0 0 4em;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        }
    li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline;
        background-color: #ccc;
        list-style: none;
        }
li:first-child:before {
        content: 'Fruit: ';
        position: absolute;
        left: -3em;
        }
```